# Using 2 ::before and 2 ::after pseudo element for 1 class

Tags: css

Hi can i know how can use 2 pseudo element for 1 class or 2 class. I tried both ways was still being overridden. Your help and advice much appreciated.

I tried 2 ways. First as below

```
<div class="custom_class">
<p>Custome Text</p>
</div>

.custom_class::before
{

}
.custom_class::after
{

}

.custom_class::before
{

}

.custom_class:::after
{

}
```

Second wat as below

```
<div class="custom_class1 custom_class2">
<p>Custome Text</p>
</div>

.custom_class1::before
{

}
.custom_class1::after
{

}

.custom_class2::before
{

}

.custom_class2:::after
{

}
```

But both not working. Can please advice on this

-------Edited------------------

This is my html code

```
<div class="classOne transx transy">
        <div class="flex-row">
        <a href="/" class="classOneBtn">Custome Text</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Added my code css code

```
.classOne {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    width: 20%;
    height: 55px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    box-shadow: 4px 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    outline: 3px solid gold;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #ffbb00;    
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.01) 0 0 1px;
    text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.01) 0 0 1px;
    margin-left:30.6%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
a.classOneBtn
{
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Chivo Black', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
}


.transy::before 
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 5px;
  background: white;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  -moz-transition: 0.3s;
  -o-transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.transy::after 
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 5px;
  background: white;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  -moz-transition: 0.3s;
  -o-transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
}

.transx::before 
{
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  -moz-transform: scaleX(0);
  -ms-transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -moz-transition: 0.3s;
  -o-transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.transx::after 
{
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  -moz-transform: scaleX(0);
  -ms-transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -moz-transition: 0.3s;
  -o-transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.transx:hover::before, .transx:hover::after 
{
  -moz-transform: scaleX(1);
  -ms-transform: scaleX(1);
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.transy:hover::before, .transy:hover::after 
{
  -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
}
```

This was for the animation part whereby when hover will show a line of box This the code which i was performing.

If you would like see output. you need comment the transx

Comment: you cannot, only one before and one after per element

Comment: omg. as i wanted do animation but it only works for 1 before and 1 after

Comment: in this case share what kind of animation you want to achieve. The solution will probably not need any pseudo element

Comment: i shared my code. thanks ya. if you would like see output. you need comment the transx

Comment: you didn't check my answer? I provided a simplified way without that amount of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same element you can not.
It is not the same item but you can get something similar.

```css
.transx{
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.classOne {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    width: 20%;
    height: 55px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    box-shadow: 4px 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    outline: 3px solid gold;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #ffbb00;    
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.01) 0 0 1px;
    text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.01) 0 0 1px;
    margin-left:30.6%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    
   
}
a.classOneBtn
{
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Chivo Black', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
}


.transy::before 
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 5px;
  background: white;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  -moz-transition: 0.3s;
  -o-transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.transy::after 
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 5px;
  background: white;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  -moz-transition: 0.3s;
  -o-transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
}

.transx::before 
{
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  -moz-transform: scaleX(0);
  -ms-transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -moz-transition: 0.3s;
  -o-transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.transx::after 
{
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  -moz-transform: scaleX(0);
  -ms-transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -moz-transition: 0.3s;
  -o-transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.transx:hover::before, .transx:hover::after 
{
  -moz-transform: scaleX(1);
  -ms-transform: scaleX(1);
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.transy:hover::before, .transy:hover::after 
{
  -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="classOne transy">
  <div class="transx"></div>
        <div class="flex-row">
          <a href="/" class="classOneBtn">Custome Text</a>
         </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wait ya will try this approach as was not working with my code. might be something wrong with my code cause thsi approach didnt work

Comment: i shared my code. thanks ya. if you would like see output. you need comment the transx

Comment: What is the problem? Can JavaScript be used to improve it?

Comment: The JavaScript thing is just because I'm better at it than CSS.

Comment: yup can. no prob. js is also allwoed

Comment: sorry. i trying it now

Comment: Is something wrong? Modified my code to add yours, I will notify you in case you do not notice it.

Comment: is good bro. only was 1 problem the text did not align center. that i will be checking now.. As the text was on top left

Comment: Close the extra DIV before the FLEX and put a text-align: center;

Comment: i tried that previously. if do like that it will work. but when i point to the text the x axist not working unless point above the text then only the x axis line was working.. for the y axis line no issue

Comment: but if if put the div after the flex div the x axis and y axis working accordingly but the text not alligned

Comment: My example is fine now, right? I don't see anything strange when selecting or anything. I will try other browsers.

Comment: i will mark as answer maybe got something parent div causing such issue. i will try troubleshoot as well

Comment: Firefox 75, Chrome 81, Edge 44 and IE 11. It looks good on everyone (in IE 11 what didn't look good was the whole page), Your animation is well done for everyone =)

Comment: hi, it solves by repositioning <div class="transx"></div> to the bottom instead of the top thanks ya

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one `::before` and one `::after` pseudo-element per element, but with some CSS magic you can make it look like the pseudo-elements of a child element belongs to its parent:

```css
*::before,
*::after {
  display: block;
}

.custom_class1::before {
  content: "outer before"
}

.custom_class1::after {
  content: "outer after"
}

.custom_class1 p::before {
  content: "inner before";
  position: absolute;
  top: -18px;
}

.custom_class1 p::after {
  content: "inner after";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -18px;
}

.custom_class1 p {
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.custom_class1 {
  background-color: pink;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom_class1 custom_class2">
  <p>Custome Text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: i shared my code. thanks ya. if you would like see output. you need comment the transx

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want without any pseudo element:

```css
.box {
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid #000;
  padding:4px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) left,
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) bottom,
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) right,
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) top;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-origin:content-box;
  background-size:5px 0%,0% 5px;
  background-color:orange;
  transition:0.5s;
}
.box:hover {
  background-size:5px 100%,100% 5px;
}

.box a {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:20px 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<a href="">text</a>
</div>
```